# User defined type as argument to elemental subroutine?

Tags: fortran, parameter-passing

In my code I have an elemental subroutine which is basically like this:

```
elemental subroutine calc_stuff (x, a, b, c)
   real, intent(in)  :: a, b, c
   real, intent(out) :: x

   x = a/b + c

end subroutine calc_stuff
```

which I changed to this:

```
elemental subroutine calc_stuff (x, a, t)
   real,         intent(in)  :: a
   type(mytype), intent(in)  :: t
   real,         intent(out) :: x

   x = a/t%b + t%c

end subroutine calc_stuff
```

where `mytype` is a type containing some scalar `real` and `integer`, as well as a `real, allocatable` array. The members `b` and `c` are `real`s, making the second version basically the same as the first one.

The second version compiles fine on various compilers (Cray, Intel, NEC, GFortran), but now I read that the standard states for elemental subroutines:

> All dummy arguments must be scalar, and must not have the ALLOCATABLE or POINTER attribute.

Is my code therefore not standard-conforming when passing a user-defined type to an elemental subroutine, but all the compilers "know" what I want because I am only using scalars from the type and not the allocatable array? Or am I misunderstanding the wording of the standard and everything is fine with the second version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dummy argument `t` is scalar<sup>1</sup> and does not have the pointer attribute and does not have the allocatable attribute.  It does not violate the condition.

The attributes of components of the type do not have a bearing on the attributes of the type itself.

---

<sup>1</sup> Being of derived type doesn't make an object necessarily non-scalar.  Even with multiple, or array components, the object itself may still be scalar.  A derived type array is an array with element(s) of that type.  Think also of a character object like `character(len=3) name`: it is scalar but consists of multiple substrings.

Comment: So a user-defined type is considered a scalar? That was not clear to me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, a derived type object can be scalar (like this one).  The usual array aspects apply the same as with intrinsic types.  Also consider the scalar `character(len=547) name` which takes multiple storage units.